# Radio Buttons - styling background onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to get this working for a while and it's not happening for me.
I want to style the background label of a radio button onclick.

Pretty much change the background of the label to full opacity (white) with a border-left: 13px solid #000;

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this?
http://www.testmethanks.com/test/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/peSJG/42/

```
.radiostyle {
    background-color: #999;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+label {
    background-color: white;
    border-left: 13px solid #000;
}


<input type="radio" name="1" value="100" id="a1">
<label for="a1" class="radiostyle">Click to make label BG whie, and add a 13px left side border</label>
```

No JS, all CSS.

Comment: Hi Sanova, That's great. Is there a way to have exactly what you coded and also have the radio buttons the way I styled them. My problem at the moment is that I can change either the background or the radio button but not both.

Comment: Can you please provide the styles you applied to the radio buttons. I will code it into my jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry, just looking into how to paste code in this forum, i haven't used it much before. I got a bit of javascript to fix my problem but would be interested to see how you solve it.